# Compare lg(lg* n) and 2^(lg*n ) in terms of asymptotic notation big-Oh, small-Oh Ω, ω, Ɵ

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

Can someone help me prove the relation between "log of log star of n" (lg(lg*(n))) and "2 power of log star of n" (2<sup>lg*n</sup>).

FYI logs are in base 2.

Comment: This question would better fit another site, such as: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you done so far to solve it yourself?

Comment: Is the any doubt that `lg(lg*n) = o(2^(lg*n)) and 2^(lg*n) = omega(lg(lg*n))` ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a math and foundations question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `f(n) = log*(n)`. Now, we should compare `log(f(n))` and `2^f(n)`. Hence, it should be straightforward to show that `log(f(n)) = o(2^f(n))`. The `o` in the notation is `little-o`. As `2^f(n)` grows exponentially and `log(f(n))` grows logarithmically. You should notice that `f(n)` is a monotinic increasing function.

Comment: This is correct, but it is maybe also worth mentioning, that for all practical purposes one can regard both functions as bounded. If n is in the order of atoms in the visible universe log*(n) is only 5.